# IllegalStateException : The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest

After updating gradle build tools to 3.6.3, I'm getting a run-time crash while trying to fetch Advertising ID which wasn't there previously.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/gms_version" />
```

values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="gms_version">@integer/google_play_services_version</integer>
</resources>
```

build.gradle

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Logcat

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 12451000 but found 6587000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:19)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source:47)
```

If I hover over 'google_play_services_version' in values.xml, it shows multiple implementations. One is version '12451000' which is coming from gms:play-services-basement-17.2.1 and the other is an internal library which is included as an aar file. It contains google play services version '6587000'. This is where the conflict occurs I guess.

The error is fixed if I hardcode the value as '12451000' in values.xml, but is there any solution other than hardcoding?

Answer (score -1):

Change it like this and make sure it is into your `<Application></Application>` tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/gms_version" />
```

You can also give direct value in your `values.xml` file. Like this,

`<integer name="gms_version">12451000</integer>`

If you don't want to hardcoded it then you can remove `.jar` file if you have added dependency in you build.gradle then you don't need to include `.jar` file in it.

Let me know if it can help you.

Thanks and Happy coding..!

Comment: Pranav : The meta data tag is already under application tag. And I have already mentioned, it will work fine if I give value directly which I don't want to. Looking for a solution which is dynamic. Didn't get the remove .jar comment. I'm using a .aar library file which is using google play service version 6587000. Thanks in advance.